# Render page in express after for loop completes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have to run mongoose query repeatedly within a for loop and once that completes, I want to render a page in express. Sample code given below. Since mongoose runs asynchronously, how can I make the 'commands/new' page to render only once the 'commands' array has been populated within the for loop?

```
...
...
var commands = [];
for (var index=0; index<ids.length; index++) {
    mongoose.model('Command').find({_id : ids[index]}, function (err, command){
        // do some biz logic with the 'command' object
        // and add it to the 'commands' array
        commands[index] = command;
    });
}

res.render('commands/new', {
    commands : commands
});
...
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic `for` loop here does not respect the callback completion of the asynchronous methods you are calling before executing each iteration. So simply use something that does instead. The node [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library fits the bill here, and in fact for even better methods of array iteration:

```js
var commands = [];

async.each(ids,function(id,callback) {
    mongoose.model("Command").findById(id,function(err,command) {
        if (command) 
            commands.push(command);
        callback(err);
    });
},function(err) {
   // code to run on completion or err
})
```

And therefore [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) or possibly a variant like `async.eachLimit` which will only run a limited number of parallel tasks as set will be your better loop iteration control methods here.

NB The `.findById()` method of Mongoose also helps shorten coding here.